# fwrite floats on one computer to be fread on another

Tags: c++, file, floating-point

I have a program that uses the following to write floats to a file, which will ultimately be read on a user's computer.

```
// computer A
float buffer[1024];
...
fwrite(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), sizeof(float), 1024, file);

// computer B
float buffer[1024];
fread(reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer), sizeof(float), 1024, file);
```

The programs on the two computers are not the same, but they are compiled with the same compiler and settings (I wouldn't expect this to work out otherwise).   Will the floats be interpreted as expected across all typical desktop computers given both programs are compiled to target the platform, or is it possible the second computer will interpret the bytes differently?

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'all typical desktop computers'? x86 architecture?

Comment: Don't do this. Use a serialization library. It may not hurt you today but one day it certainly will.

Comment: @Michael - that's probably the case, I used 'typical desktop' to get a more practical answer, since I figure it becomes a very nuanced subject once you consider architectures in microcontrollers, super computers, etc

Comment: @EJP can you give an example of how it might hurt him?  The only gotchas I can think of are endian-ness mismatch (a problem that seems to be going away) or a hypothetical new CPU that doesn't use the common floating point format (which doesn't seem terribly likely, at least not for desktop software).  Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The programs on the two computers are not the same, but they are
>   compiled with the same compiler and settings (I wouldn't expect this
>   to work out otherwise). Will the floats be interpreted as expected
>   across all typical desktop computers, or is it possible the second
>   computer will interpret the bytes differently?

Pretty much all modern desktop computers use [IEEE 754 floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) for their single-precision floating point numbers, so you should be okay.

One potential fly in the ointment is endian-ness:  if you write out the file on a computer with a big-endian CPU and then read it on a computer that has a little-endian CPU (or vice-versa) then the reading computer will not interpret the file's values correctly.  This is not a big problem in the last few years since almost all commonly used CPUs are little-endian these days, but previously that problem was commonly seen e.g. when transferring data from an Intel-based computer to a PowerPC-based computer, or vice-versa.  A common way to handle the problem would be to specify a standard/canonical endian-ness (doesn't matter which one) for the values in your file, and be sure to byte-swap the values when saving (or loading) the file if the computer you are saving/loading them on doesn't match the canonical endian-ness specified by your file format.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate question...

It is *definitely* possible that the format can be interpreted differently.

However, you said "typical desktop computers", which generally means x86, x64, maybe ARM. But all of these use little-endian binary formats. So in practice you'd probably be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on compiler. But to avoid problems you can check some features of `float` for platform.
E.g. check `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits`, and if is 24, it means that compiler using the IEEE standard double-precision for `float`.